# Dynamic height layout with RecyclerView inside

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

everyone.

I'm struggling with a layout here where I have a component made with ConstraintLayout. Inside this component, I have a fixed title and a RecyclerView right below, which is supposed to scroll respecting this title.

When my component has up to 6 elements, it has a `wrap_content` to match the size of the elements. If it has more than 6 elements, I have fix the component size to `1000px`.

The problem is: When I have more than 6 elements, the RecyclerView is not been displayed correctly. The last elements are cutted off. By my understanding, looks like the view of the component has a bigger size than it looks when rendering, which is making me crazy to fix it.

Here is my component code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/component_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_card_with_radius"
    android:maxHeight="1000px"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="1000px"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:paddingStart="16px"
    android:paddingEnd="16px"
    android:paddingTop="32px"
    android:paddingBottom="32px"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedColorValue">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/StandardText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:text="@string/title_hdr" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:divider_visibility="gone"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the code to call it:

```
<components.CardComponent
        android:id="@+id/card_component"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/card_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

I've already tried to create a NestedScrollView around the RecyclerView, also to set an extra padding in the parent layout and other many things. But the main idea was to make the RecyclerView scrollable and the component be with a dynamic height with less than 6 items.

The expected:
[image]

Can anyone can give some light on that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try  `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` in your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Didn't work. =/

Comment: It is working for me. Why have you set constraintLayouts's height to 1000px? Don't you want you recycler view to cover full screen?

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya my has dynamic height and can be expanded at a maximum of 1000px

Comment: So you fixed you height to 1000px, and now when recycler view has items that take more than 1000px, it will scroll to show the items below? What the issue? Is recycler view not scrolling?

Comment: Quick Tip: Don't use pixel values, instead use dp, which is Device Independent Pixel.

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya I know, but this is a specific requirement for the project I'm working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**used this xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".presentation.activities.SeeActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/box_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Rahul Rokade"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="8999539845"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_above="@id/box_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:scrollIndicators="right"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```