# How to make a scrollable layout been just followed by another layout in an Android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Here is what I want to get in my Android activity:

```
+------------------++------------------++------------------+
| +--------------+ || +--------------+ || +--------------+ |
| |    Table     | || |    Table     | || |    Table    #| |
| |              | || |              | || |             #| |
| |              | || |              | || |             #| |
| |              | || |              | || |             #| |
| +--------------+ || |              | || |             #| |
| +--------------+ || |              | || |             #| |
| | Linearlayout | || |              | || |             #| |
| +--------------+ || +--------------+ || |              | |
|                  || +--------------+ || |              | |
|                  || | Linearlayout | || +--------------+ |
|                  || +--------------+ || +--------------+ |
|                  ||                  || | Linearlayout | |
|                  ||                  || +--------------+ |
|  +------------+  ||  +------------+  ||  +------------+  |
|  |   Button   |  ||  |   Button   |  ||  |   Button   |  |
|  +------------+  ||  +------------+  ||  +------------+  |
+------------------++------------------++------------------+
```

Goals:

- I have a table of variable length.
- The table shall be scrollable if it cannot be fully displayed
- I want the Linearlayout to always be next to the table
- The button shall always be positioned at the bottom

I have tried many combinations of ConstraintLayout and Linearlayout without success:

- Or the Linearlayout  disappears when the table is too long
- Or the Linearlayout stays close to the Button.

Here is an example of code (simplified) that does not work:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/B2"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/S1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0">
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/table"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableRow >...</TableRow>
                <TableRow >...</TableRow>
                <TableRow >...</TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>.....</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button android:id="@+id/B2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="validate"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know I can achieve this by using an OnPreDrawListener, but I would prefer to have something more static, just with layouts in XML.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please refer this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76932214/dynamic-height-layout-with-recyclerview-inside/76944534#76944534 . And First confirm view . I think this is simple scroll view list. This is not a table view.

Comment: This is unfortunately not the same issue and not the same context (RecyclerView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, atleast in the preview it did:
I hope I understood your requirements correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/green_like">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"/>

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/red_400">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/green_like">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="validate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

LinearLayout is blue, table cellsgreen and red

[image: small table]

[image: big table]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple and nice code example. I was almost there in one of my many tests.
The only thing missing was the second "app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"" (in the linearlayout)

Comment: I have added some complexity to my android activity, and I cannot tweak your solution to make it work in my new context.
Just in case, the link to the new post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78135030

Answer (score 0):

[image]
*try this*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activity.SettingsActivity">
<include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/hh_one"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="one"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorGray"/>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/tb_one">
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorOrange"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorRed"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPinkLight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hh_one"
            android:layout_below="@id/tb_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rahul"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/hh_two"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="two"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorGray"/>
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tb_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorGray"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hh_two"
            android:layout_below="@id/tb_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rahul"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/hh_three"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="three"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorGray"/>
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tb_three"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorOrange"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorRed"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hh_three"
            android:layout_below="@id/tb_three"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rahul"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this example. Unfortunately, I does not work as my expectations: if you add more rows to the table, the table overlaps the button.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer is repeated, let’s change the plan for your reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexDirection="column">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/S1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_flexShrink="1000">

        <!--TableLayout-->
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llOther"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!--...-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="validate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this example. Unfortunately, I does not work as my expectations: the bottom LinearLayout needs to be always visible, but in the example, it is part of the scrollview