# How to make a scrollable layout been just followed by another layout in an Android activity (second part)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

This is the continuation of [How to make a scrollable layout been just followed by another layout in an Android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78072942)

I used the solution proposed by [Finn Marquardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11608990/finn-marquardt).

Compared to the expectations of this previous post, I now want the ScrollView to be in a block containing also a title and a border to be displayed around this block, like this:

[image] [image]

I managed to do this by adding an extra FrameLayout just to display the border.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/prop1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/extra_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/title_block"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/scrollView" />

    <LinearLayout android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/title_block"
            android:paddingVertical="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
        <TextView android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:text="TITLE"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_block"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow android:background="#ff9999">
                <TextView android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="first row"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:background="#99ff99">
                <TextView android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="second row"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:background="#bbbbff">
                <TextView android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="third row"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="validate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But I don't like this idea of adding an artificial layout just for the border.
I would prefer to have a layout (with a border) including the title and the ScrollView.

How can I do that?

Comment: give background to scrollview

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use two recycler view which is by default scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

From your questions what I understand could be your solution is a hierarchy as follows

```
<SomeLayout>
   <SomeToolbar/>
     <SomeScrollView>
         <VirticalLinearLayoutWrap>
              <YourTableLayout>
                 <!--Stuffhere-->
              </YourTableLayout>
         </VirticalLinearLayoutWrap>

         <AnotherVirticalLinearLayoutWrap>
                 <!--Stuffhere-->
         </AnotherVirticalLinearLayoutWrapEnds>
    </SomeScrollEnds>

    <SomeButton/>

 </SomeLayoutEnds>
```

Hope it helps